# как объявить переменную в аргументах функции

Tags: c, gcc

Подскажите пожалуйста, как объявить переменную в аргументах функции?
Существует функция принимающяя указатель. Необходимо передать ей адрес переменной созданой временно на стеке в момент вызова функции, соответственно и жить данная переменная будет только в момент вызова и работы функции

Нужно чтото наподобе

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo (int *a)
{
   printf ("%p\n", a);
}

int main (void)
{
   foo (&{int a=1});
   return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку

```
gcc a.c
a.c: In function 'main':
a.c:10: error: expected expression before '{' token
```

Возможно нужно указать стандарт, наподобе `-c99` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Правильный синтаксис для вызова с *составным литералом* (*compound literal*) в качестве аргумента в С99

```
 foo(&(int) { 1 });
```

Судя по написанному, вы пытались "нащупать" именно этот синтаксис.

Однако жить такой безымянный объект будет в общем случае несколько дольше, чем вы хотите - он имеет обычный автоматический класс памяти и живет до конца охватывающего блока (явного или неявного).

Фактически нет никакой разницы между таким объектом и явно объявленной перед вызовом переменной: и тот, и другой будут жить в локальной памяти (стеке) вызывающей функции. Только пространство имен не захламляется еще одним, возможно никому больше не нужным, именем.

Comment: Да, данная конструкция работает и это подходит для моей задачи. Единственный оставшийся вопрос, скорее уже из "научного любопытства" - как не просто передать адрес на константу лежащую на стеке, а именно переменную? Вариант `foo($(int){int a=1});` вызвал такую же ошибку компилятора даже с указанием `-std=c99`

Comment: @PeterK. Не понимаю вопроса. Данный вариант передает адрес именно *переменной*, а не какой-то "константы". Безымянной переменной. Хотите, чтобы у переменной было имя - объявляйте ее как обычно.

Comment: был неточен. Да, я имел ввиду чтобы у переменной было имя. Хотя де-факто это совершенно ненужно. Интересует больше почему компилятор спокойно воспринимает безымянную переменную, но ругается если я пытаюсь в тех же фигурных скобках объявить переменную с именем.

Comment: @PeterK. Потому что в языке С вообще нет возможности объявить именованную переменную так, как вы ее пытаетесь объявить. То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, можно сделать только отдельно стоящим объявлением. Однако непонятно зачем вы хотите засунуть объявление именно туда.

Comment: Ок, спасибо за комент. Я когда-то натыкался на конструкцию с объявлением в аргументах функции, но не смог ни найти ни вспомнить. Возможно это была какая-то специфичная модификация gcc.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo (int *a)
{
   printf ("%p\n", a);
}

int main (void)
{
   int a = 1;
   foo (&a);
   return 0;
}
```

Если же задача состоит в написание макроса, чтоб незахломлять область видимости своими переменными и не переживать за наличие уникальных имен для этих переменных, можно использовать операторные скобки

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo (int *a)
{
    printf ("%p\n", a);
}

int main (void)
{
    {
        int a = 1;
        foo (&a);
    }

    {   
        int a = 2;
        foo (&a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет, интересует именно боъявление на стеке. Не отдельно.

Comment: переменная int a = 1; объявлена на стеке

Comment: поправлюсь - интересует объявление в аргументах при выхове функции. Внутри скобок

Comment: @Peter K. ну уверен на 100%, но мне кажется, что это невозможно.

Comment: моя изначальная задача более сложна, содержит макросы и необходимо измежать объявления переменной отдельной строкой. Необходимо чтобы переменная создалась в момент вызова фунции и просуществовала только до конца работы функции, использовать ее гделибо еще не планируеться

Comment: дело в том что я этот пример уже видел и пробовал, и оно работало. Увы не могу найти опять в гугле, поэтому и пишу тут

Comment: заверните свой макрос в `do { ... } while(0);` и объявляйте отдельной строкой.

Comment: @Peter K. дополнил ответ

Comment: да, можно, но я бы хотел избежать лишних конструкций, так как дальше все только усложниться.

Comment: Если таких конструкций много, а вы хотите сделать "сокращение", то используйте `#define` например `#define foo_i(x)  { int def_a=x; foo(&def_a);}` и вызывайте `foo_i(1);foo_i(2);`

Comment: @PeterK похоже, что уже есть усложение на ровном месте (попытка оптимизации). Пишите задачу детальнее, примерчик, а там и решение подтянется